# How can I manipulate my array, so if there is a scan within 60min with the same

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

This is really hard to explain, but i will do my best.

I have a array called **arrayoftransationcs** which contains 4 strings. ***SCAN, MEMBER_ID, RESTAURANT, TIME, PAID**. If a scan is paid, it will defined as 1, and if not it will have 0.

So the main question to my problem is, how can I get scan that contain paid = 0 which has not have paid = 1 within 60 min. I will give an example.

**Example A** In this example, there is 3 scan which comes from the same cafe x within 20 min. The first 2 has been defined as paid = 0, and the last has been defined as paid = 1. Because there is paid = 1 within 60min with the same member_id and restaurant, i dont want any of the scan

```
Scan A  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 21:00    Paid 1  
Scan B  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 20:50    Paid 0  
Scan C  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 20:40    Paid 0
```

**Example B** In this example, there is also 3 scan from the same member, same restaurant, within 60min, but all of them has been defined as paid = 0. Because there is no paid = 1 in this example, i want these in a array. This is the goal. *But there is a twist here, because there is more than 1 scan to use, i only want the latest scan in this example, which will mean only scan A can be used*

```
Scan A  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 21:00    Paid 0  
Scan B  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 20:50    Paid 0  
Scan C  1635752   Cafe X    17-11-2013 20:40    Paid 0
```

So I hope you understand the my question. I need paid = 0 scan if there is not a paid = 1 scan subsequently with the same member_id, restaurant within 60min

This is how i tried.

I am looping my array 2 times, and then checking for it the same member_id (cardid) and restaurants are equals together, if yes, then check time. If it is whitin 60min, mark the scan as double

```
 foreach($arrayoftransationcs as $key => $array)
  {
    $time=$arrayoftransationcs[$key]['created'];
    $cardid = $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['cardid'];
    $restaurant_id = $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['restaurant_id'];

    if(isset($arrayoftransationcs[$key]))
    {
        foreach($arrayoftransationcs as $k1=>$v1)
        {
            $time2=$arrayoftransationcs[$k1]['created'];

            if($key<$k1)
            {
                if($arrayoftransationcs[$k1]['cardid']==$cardid && $arrayoftransationcs[$k1]['restaurant_id']==$restaurant_id)
                {
                    if(compare($time,$time2))
                    {   

                        $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['error'] = 'double';
                        $arrayoftransationcs[$k1]['error'] = 'double';                         
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }   
  }
```

---

checking the time here.

```
 function compare($firsttime, $secondtime)
 {
     $interval = $firsttime-$secondtime;
     $dif=round(abs($interval) / 60);
     if ($dif < 60 || $dif < -60 ) 
     {
        if ($dif!==0) 
        {
             return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
   }
```

---

This is the place, where i filter after paid = 0 and does not contain anything in the error field.

```
  foreach ($arrayoftransationcs as $key) 
  {
    if($key['paid'] == 0 && empty($key['error']))
    {
            $ids[] = $key['transactionid'];

     }
  }
```

---

But I am not sure it is the right approach, I did it with the code. For technically, I select all scan which has the same membership number, restaurant with "double" in the field error, if it is paid = 1 or 0, does not matter .. this is not right, i think.

So I'm missing something here, checking if there is paid = 0 scan here if yes, check if there is a paid = 1 scan within the next 60min having the same medlem_id and restaurant. If so, then mark them as doubles.

Comment: Can you `print_r()` your array and post it somewhere (pastebin?) or here?

Comment: i have posted my array in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kYzKKjJD

Comment: Sorry, that is a crazy. Cant see the array structure properly. Can you try this and post it to pastebin again? `echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrayoftransationcs); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Ohh, my bad.. new vers. http://pastebin.com/Ni95uF5S

Comment: much better. To summerise, from this array, you are trying to determine who hasn't paid within 1 hour?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. Give me a few minutes, will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
<?php

// Data Source
$arrayoftransationcs = array(
    array(
        'transactionid' => 16148,
        'cardid' => 10010234,
        'created' => 1380650784,
        'restaurant_id' => 32089,
        'paid' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'transactionid' => 16552,
        'cardid' => 10010241,
        'created' => 1381522288,
        'restaurant_id' => 41149,
        'paid' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'transactionid' => 16936,
        'cardid' => 10010440,
        'created' => 1386247655,
        'restaurant_id' => 47897,
        'paid' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'transactionid' => 16808,
        'cardid' => 10010557,
        'created' => 1382361447,
        'restaurant_id' => 43175,
        'paid' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'transactionid' => 18932,
        'cardid' => 10010440,
        'created' => 1386247655,
        'restaurant_id' => 47897,
        'paid' => 1
    )
);

// Helper Function
function getUnpaidWithinHour($transactions) {
    $unpaid_transactions = array();
    $time_now = time();
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        if ($transaction['paid']) continue;
        if (($time_now - $transaction['created']) < 3600 && !$transaction['paid']) {
            $unpaid_transactions[] = $transaction;
        }
    }
    return $unpaid_transactions;
}

// Test
$unpaid_transactions = getUnpaidWithinHour($arrayoftransationcs);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unpaid_transactions);
echo "<pre>";

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transactionid] => 16936
            [cardid] => 10010440
            [created] => 1386247655
            [restaurant_id] => 47897
            [paid] => 0
        )

)
```

To test if this is working, I edited the transaction **16936** to have a timestamp of 5 minutes ago and ran the function. The code correctly detected that transaction.

Try it yourself and with your own datasource.

Comment: If you add, on more to your array, example array(
        'transactionid' => 18932,
        'cardid' => 10010440,
        'created' => 1386243624,
        'restaurant_id' => 47897,
        'paid' => 1
    )

then you output 16936, should not work, because there is a paid=1 within 60 min with the same member_id, restaurant. but according to your code, it works.

Comment: still the same @Latheesan. And if there is more than one unpaid scan, with no paid=1 after within 60min with same member_id and restaurant, both of unpaid scan will appear.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what the problem is here. Can you explain your requirement again, simple as possible? I've updated my code again. In this, i have two entries (16936, 18932) both having same timestamp (within past 5 mins), but 18932 is marked as paid. When I run the script, I only get one entry - as expected.

Comment: Because 18932 is marked as paid, then it means 16936, should not appear. The reason is, entry 16936 has not paid there transaction, but couple of minutes later, the member decided to pay again, this time the tansaction has been succesful (marked as paid).

That is the reason why I only want those unpaid entries where there has been not paid subsequent (within 60min, with the same member_id and restaurant)

Comment: If you look what I posted, there are 2 examples. (A and B) As you can see in the example B, then the same member_id been out to eat at Cafe X. He has tried to pay 3 times, but all of them have not gone through. Hence, only the last is displayed.

But if you look at the example A, then a member also tried to pay 3 times, the first 2 times not through, but the last time worked perfectly. Therefore, none of these 3 should appear

Answer (score 1):

Let's make things simple, your question is: **Find paid = 0 scan if there is not paid = 1 with same member_id within 60min**, since lack of test data, so i'll describe below with nature language in php style:

```
make an empty arrayPaid

foreach (all data) {
    if time passed greater than 60min, continue;

    if paid
        add member_id in arrayPaid: arrayPaid[member_id] = something
        continue;

    if unpaid and arrayPaid[member_id] is not set
        this is the data you want
}
```

The logic is clear, easy to write your real code. And one important thing is, your data need to be order by time in desc.

Comment: Here is my array pastebin.com/Ni95uF5S

Comment: Give me some minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by doing this.

```
 foreach ($results->result_array() as $filterofresults) 
  {
    if($filterofresults['paid'] == 1)
    {
      $arrayoftransationcs1[]=$filterofresults;

    }
        if($filterofresults['paid'] == 0)
    {
      $arrayoftransationcs[]=$filterofresults;

    }
  }

  foreach($arrayoftransationcs as $key => $array)
  {
    $time=$arrayoftransationcs[$key]['created'];
    $cardid = $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['cardid'];
    $restaurant_id = $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['restaurant_id'];

    if(isset($arrayoftransationcs[$key]))
    {
        foreach($arrayoftransationcs1 as $k1=>$v1)
        {
            $time2=$arrayoftransationcs1[$k1]['created'];

            if($key<$k1)
            {
                if($arrayoftransationcs1[$k1]['cardid']==$cardid && $arrayoftransationcs1[$k1]['restaurant_id']==$restaurant_id)
                {
                    if(compare($time,$time2))
                    {   

                        $arrayoftransationcs[$key]['error'] = 'Dobbelt';
                        $arrayoftransationcs1[$k1]['error'] = 'Dobbelt';  

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }   
  }
  foreach ($arrayoftransationcs as $key) 
  {

    if($key['paid'] == 0 && empty($key['error']))
    {
            $samlet[] = get_all_data($key['transactionid']);
     }
  }
```